# How do i pass parameters from first cdk stack's output to another cdk stack's input, when deploying using jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cdk

I have one bitbucket repository, in that, I have 4 CDK stacks in a separate folder. Now I want to create a Jenkins pipeline, Like in the first stage the first stack has been built and deployed,

now I want to use the first stack outputs as second stack's inputs and the same for the third and fouth folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use another stack's output, use the [`Fn.importValue` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Fn.html#static-importwbrvaluesharedvaluetoimport).

Like this:

```python
imported_output = cdk.Fn.import_value("OUTPUT_NAME")
```

A good alternative would be to deploy all of your stacks together in a single CDK app and just pass the object references between your stacks.

CDK will figure out the necessary outputs/imports under the hood, and will deploy the stacks in the correct order automatically.

Here's an example from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resource_stack):

```python
prod = cdk.Environment(account="123456789012", region="us-east-1")

stack1 = StackThatProvidesABucket(app, "Stack1", env=prod)

# stack2 will take a property "bucket"
stack2 = StackThatExpectsABucket(app, "Stack2", bucket=stack1.bucket, env=prod)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I completely got your answer.

imported_output = cdk.Fn.import_value("OUTPUT_NAME")

this function is working for if one CDK App has multiple stacks.

But my question is regarding, One Bitbucket having multiple CDK App

Comment: No, this works between stacks. It doesn't matter how these stacks are deployed - with one CDK app, with multiple, or with plain CloudFormation. It will also work with multiple CDK apps.